# Laravel components data passing

Tags: laravel

can someone tell me what is the problem in this component...
Here is the error:

```
Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\...\resources\views\components\sidebar-users.blade.php)
```

Here is that view/component:

```
<div>
<!-- Users Widget -->
<div class="card my-4">
    <h5 class="card-header">Latest Users</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        <li>{{ $user }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is home blade view where component is called:

```
@section('sidebar')
    <!-- Search Widget -->
    <x-sidebar-search></x-sidebar-search>

    <!-- Users Widget -->
    <x-sidebar-users></x-sidebar-users>

    <!-- Side Text Widget -->
    <x-sidebar-text-widget></x-sidebar-text-widget>
@endsection
```

Here is component:

```
 <?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class SidebarUsers extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
/**
 * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
 */
public function render()
{
    return view('components.sidebar-users', [
        'users' => $this->users()
    ]);
}

public function users()
{
    return User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
}
```

I have done it this way because I have done it with posts same and it worked without problems.
I have also tried to send data from my controller

```
.....'users' => User::orderBy....
```

Then in __construct

```
public $users;



 ...  __construct($users){
$this->users=$users;
}
```

Then to accept it in home blade like

```
.... <x-sidebar-users :users="$users"/> ...
```

And I get same error... Anyone know solution?

Comment: Which version Laravel do you use? Is location of component `App\View\Components\ SidebarUsers .php`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove that function users and try something like this,

```
public function render(){
$users = User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
return view('components.sidebar-users' , compact('users'));
}
```

Seems to me like you are overcomplicating things... Keep it simple

Comment: Same error again, I was following laravel docs when was doing that :3

Comment: Are you sure you are getting results returned from the query? Do a dd on users and tell me what you see

Comment: The variable should be in your view, do this in your view before the loop, ```{{dd($users)}}```

Comment: It shows all five inputs that were sent from db... same as at the prev. photo I am a bit confused now xD

Comment: Ok so the variable is definetly in your view. And you still get the same error ```Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\...\resources\views\components\sidebar-users.blade.php)
``` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad... when I call $users from view I get closure, check it out here: 
https://prnt.sc/vao1hl

Comment: Did you remove the ```__construct()``` aswell?

Comment: I did not remove anything.. __construct is just empty

Answer (score 0):

At first, you don't have to call `users()` method manually.

Secondly, have you tried to clear all the cache? I recall the same error was because of cache.

Comment: I have cleared but same again :3 But what do you mean I don't need to call users() manually?

Comment: You don't have to pass it as parameter for `view` function.

Comment: BTW, try `dd('component created')` in constructor to check whether it was created or not.

Comment: It is created I used make:component with php artisan

Comment: I mean in runtime